# How to upload or use existing asset image using Carrierwave uploader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, carrierwave

User has to options:

- choose one of three images from my assets folder
- upload his own

I am wondering if I can set up CarrierWave uploader to handle both cases.

So I don't want to upload file for chosen one. So I tried to update column for that.

```
user.update_column(:avatar, 'assets/images/default_avatar_1.jpg')
```

But then when I am using `user.avatar.url` uploader looks for this file in public folder as specified.

Is possible to override this behaviour?